# php function to make plain line breaks into a list

Tags: php, line

I have a variable $boo that contains lines of plain text like (with singular line breaks):

a

b

c

I want a function to format it into a bullet list. Have come up with the following, but can't quiet get anything to output:

```
<?php
function listformat ($list) {
    $listformat = explode("\n", $listformat);
    foreach ($listformat as $test => $line) {
        return "<li>".$line."</li>";
    };
};
?>

<ul>
<?php
listformat ($boo);
?>
</ul>
```

It works if I use echo in place of "return" and remove the function.

Comment: Figured out I should either echo listformat ($boo); or echo it inside the function if I'm going to use return, which shouldn't be done inside the foreach loop anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` ends your function and sends the statement back to whatever called it. So, yes, echo is necessary

```
<?php
function listformat ($list) {
    $listformat = explode("\n", $list);
    foreach ($listformat as $line) {
        echo "<li>".$line."</li>";
    };
};

echo '<ul>';
listformat($my_list_var);
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still keep the function, but instead of `echo` or `return`, build the HTML output with a local variable and return it at the end:

```
<?php
function listformat ($list) {
    $output = '<ul>';
    $listformat = explode("\n", $list);
    foreach ($listformat as $test => $line) {
        $output .= "<li>".$line."</li>";
    };
    return $output.'</ul>';
};
?>
```

Now you can use your function wherever you want and either echo the returned value or do whatever you want:

```
<?php
echo(listformat($list));
?>
```

Comment: This function is outputting nothing.

<?php
function listformat ($list) {
 $output = '';
 $listformat = explode("\n", $listformat);
 foreach ($listformat as $test => $line) {
  $output = "<li>".$line."</li>";
 };
 return $output;
};
echo '<ul>';
listformat ($boo);
echo '</ul>';
?>

Comment: Your function doesn't use `$list`. I fell into the same trap as well because the OP also has it wrong. You need to explode `$list`

Comment: Good find! Proof my naming conventions suck. Also had to use echo instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
function ln2ul($string) {
  return '<ul><li>' . str_replace("\n", '</li><li>', trim($string)) . '</li></ul>';
}
```